# Bijective and holomorphic function between $\{z\vert 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$ and $\{z\vert \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am supposed to contruct a bijective holomorphic function $f(z)$ between $S:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\vert 0<\operatorname{Re}(z)<1\}$ and $OH:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\vert \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$ where $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ is the real part function and $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ is the imaginary part function.

Does anyone have an idea how I can construct such a function? What I am doing is not really more than just guessing.
I tried functions like $z^n$, but that does not work since the angles get way too big. Rotation by multiplying $i$ gets the stripe S in the right direction, but i struggle to expand it to the entire set $OH$. I tried doing this by using $1/z$, (so $f(z)=i/z$), but that map is not surjective since I cant reach $i$ for example. Special functions like $\exp$ does not seem to work either.

I am not asking for an entire solution, just for some hints how I approach this exercise. How would you try to solve it? Because guessing is probably not the best strategy

Comment: Hint: $z \mapsto e^z$ takes the strip $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \operatorname{Im}(z) < \frac{\pi}{2}$ to the right half plane $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$.

Comment: Would this work?: Rotate S using $\cdot i$, scale it with $\cdot\pi$, shift it with $-\frac{\pi}{2}i$, apply exponential function, and then rotate with $i$ again, so $ f(z) = ie^{i\pi z - i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but now that you have it, you should see if you can simplify it.